# Installing Ruby 1.8.7 on Mac Os C 10.9.2

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mavericks

I need to install ruby 1.8.7 on Mac Os x 10.9. I have run into several problems and have not found the answer. I have X code 5.1.1 and command line tools installed. What ever I do, I always get this same error message:

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p374.
It is not possible to build movable binaries for rubies 1.8-1.9.2, but you can do it for        your system only.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on     binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
Installing requirements for osx_brew.
Updating system....
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, gcc46, libyaml, readline, libksba, openssl098...
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config gcc46 libyaml readline libksba openssl098',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/elisabethwork/.rvm/log/1399001508_ruby-1.8.7-p374/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_gcc46_libyaml_readline_libksba_openssl098.log
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 1 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ case "$_system_version" in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.

$ brew doctor

Your system is ready to brew.
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: "There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log." - Good advice there, last 15 lines don't show the actual error. Also note that MRI 1.8.7 has been obsoleted - there is no official support for it any more. AFAIK, REE (`rvm install ree`) is still at 1.8.7 compatibility, maybe that will work for you. But best advice, try to upgrade whatever your software is for 1.9 or 2.x, if at all possible.

Comment: Sorry, REE is at 1.8.6. You can do `rvm install ree-1.8.7` for 1.8.7, if it works.

Comment: Thank you Amadan. I tried to upgrade the software but it seems like I have accidentally removed ruby from the system. When I run 

$ ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found

how can I get ruby back?

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to upgrade the software", and how did you accidentally remove Ruby? What does `rvm list` say? Did you try to install any other Ruby? What happened?

Comment: I mean I upgraded software. I don't know did I removed it. 

rvm list

rvm rubies

# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'. I did not try to install other rubies yet. I'm now ensuring that I have the command line tools installed.

Comment: I really have no idea what to try next. Any tips?

Comment: Try `rvm install 2.1` for new Ruby, `rvm install ree-1.8.7` for old one.

Comment: It did not help I got the same kind of error as earlier :/  

$rvm install 2.1

Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libyaml readline libksba openssl',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/elisabethwork/.rvm/log/1399262921_ruby-2.1.1/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_libyaml_readline_libksba_openssl.log

Comment: I already addressed that. Last 15 lines of the log are not sufficient to show the error. Go and read the log a bit further up to find the error.

Comment: The results was that I uninstalled RVM and installed ruby with Rbenv, it works so much better. Thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

See this bash script which lets you switch between 1.8.7 en 2.0. No RVM, brew or other extra software needed:  https://gist.github.com/mipmip/7cfbadfcfa5fabe0ba84

Answer (score 0):

for my case. I previously installed the `autoconf` `libtool` module myself and home-brew want to override that.  so you have to manually tell **brew** that.

```
brew link --overwrite autoconf
...
```

you should run `brew doctor` and spend sometime read keywords like: **error**,**build**